# Why does my pyopencl image manipulation stop working when I switch to color?

Tags: python, opencv, gpu, opencl, pyopencl

I'm trying to make a very simple GPU implementation of a lerp between two images in python and opencl (as my first ever opencl project, lol).  It works when I use grayscale images, but gives nothing (not even any errors!) when I switch to color.  My images are just 3 4000x4000 jpgs.

Here is my *working* code for grayscale:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyopencl as cl

def apply_skinnify_filter(mask, dark, light):

    # (1) setup OpenCL
    platforms = cl.get_platforms() # a platform corresponds to a driver (e.g. AMD)
    platform = platforms[0] # take first platform
    devices = platform.get_devices(cl.device_type.GPU) # get GPU devices of selected platform
    device = devices[0] # take first GPU
    context = cl.Context([device]) # put selected GPU into context object
    queue = cl.CommandQueue(context, device) # create command queue for selected GPU and context

    # (2) get shape of input image, allocate memory for output to which result can be copied to
    shape = mask.T.shape
    img_out = np.empty_like(mask)

    # (2) create image buffers which hold images for OpenCL
    mask_in_buf = cl.Image(context, cl.mem_flags.READ_ONLY, cl.ImageFormat(cl.channel_order.LUMINANCE, cl.channel_type.UNORM_INT8), shape=shape)
    dark_in_buf = cl.Image(context, cl.mem_flags.READ_ONLY, cl.ImageFormat(cl.channel_order.LUMINANCE, cl.channel_type.UNORM_INT8), shape=shape)
    light_in_buf = cl.Image(context, cl.mem_flags.READ_ONLY, cl.ImageFormat(cl.channel_order.LUMINANCE, cl.channel_type.UNORM_INT8), shape=shape)
    img_out_buf = cl.Image(context, cl.mem_flags.WRITE_ONLY, cl.ImageFormat(cl.channel_order.LUMINANCE, cl.channel_type.UNORM_INT8), shape=shape)

    # (3) load and compile OpenCL program
    program = cl.Program(context, open('kernel.cl').read()).build()

    # (3) from OpenCL program, get kernel object and set arguments (input image, operation type, output image)
    kernel = cl.Kernel(program, 'morphOpKernel') # name of function according to kernel.py
    kernel.set_arg(0, mask_in_buf) # input image buffer
    kernel.set_arg(1, dark_in_buf) # input image buffer
    kernel.set_arg(2, light_in_buf) # input image buffer
    kernel.set_arg(3, img_out_buf) # output image buffer

    # (4) copy image to device, execute kernel, copy data back
    cl.enqueue_copy(queue, mask_in_buf, mask, origin=(0, 0), region=shape, is_blocking=False)
    cl.enqueue_copy(queue, dark_in_buf, dark, origin=(0, 0), region=shape, is_blocking=False)
    cl.enqueue_copy(queue, light_in_buf, light, origin=(0, 0), region=shape, is_blocking=False)
    cl.enqueue_nd_range_kernel(queue, kernel, shape, None)
    cl.enqueue_copy(queue, img_out, img_out_buf, origin=(0, 0), region=shape, is_blocking=True)

    return img_out


def main():

    # read image
    mask = cv2.imread('images/mask.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    dark = cv2.imread('images/dark.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    light = cv2.imread('images/light.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

    filtered = apply_skinnify_filter(mask, dark, light)
    cv2.imwrite('images/filtered.jpg', filtered)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And my kernel:

```
__constant sampler_t sampler = CLK_NORMALIZED_COORDS_FALSE | CLK_FILTER_NEAREST | CLK_ADDRESS_CLAMP_TO_EDGE;

float4 lerp(float4 a, float4 b, float4 w)
{
  return a + w*(b-a);
}

__kernel void morphOpKernel(__read_only image2d_t mask, __read_only image2d_t dark, __read_only image2d_t light, __write_only image2d_t out)
{
    const int x = get_global_id(0);
    const int y = get_global_id(1);

    float4 maskPixel = read_imagef(mask, sampler, (int2)(x, y));
    float4 lightPixel = read_imagef(light, sampler, (int2)(x, y));
    float4 darkPixel = read_imagef(dark, sampler, (int2)(x, y));
    float4 pixel = lerp(darkPixel, lightPixel, maskPixel);

    write_imagef(out, (int2)(x, y), pixel);
}
```

Now, when I want to do it in color, I try to change the buffer creation lines like so (from LUMINANCE to RGBA):

```
mask_in_buf = cl.Image(context, cl.mem_flags.READ_ONLY, cl.ImageFormat(cl.channel_order.RGBA, cl.channel_type.UNORM_INT8), shape=shape)
dark_in_buf = cl.Image(context, cl.mem_flags.READ_ONLY, cl.ImageFormat(cl.channel_order.RGBA, cl.channel_type.UNORM_INT8), shape=shape)
light_in_buf = cl.Image(context, cl.mem_flags.READ_ONLY, cl.ImageFormat(cl.channel_order.RGBA, cl.channel_type.UNORM_INT8), shape=shape)
img_out_buf = cl.Image(context, cl.mem_flags.WRITE_ONLY, cl.ImageFormat(cl.channel_order.RGBA, cl.channel_type.UNORM_INT8), shape=shape)
```

And the lines in python when I read in the images like so (from GRAYSCALE to COLOR):

```
mask = cv2.imread('images/mask.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
dark = cv2.imread('images/dark.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
light = cv2.imread('images/light.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

And.... I get nothing.  When I run it, it pauses a second like it is doing work, and then I get no file, no errors, no nothing, lol.

Help.

Comment: When using grayscale there was only one dimension whereas in color there is 3 or 4 dimensions. Have a look for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39637325/4899330 for how to properly write image to CL buffer when having many dimensions.

Comment: @doqtor Thanks for the hint!  Unfortunately I don't understand OpenCL enough to quite follow that code or understand how to use the function.  Would you might explaining further?   At least how I might go about using that function in my code?

Comment: Just use that example to figure out how to fill `cl.Image` and use `cl.enqueue_copy` when there is image with more than 1 dimension.